# I can't make a get request on the Api react native

Tags: javascript

I can't make a get request on the Api

I tried to make an application that will show statistics of players in Dota, but I can’t make a request to the API,
I divided the main screen and the block where I connect the api to different files

[(https://docs.stratz.com/api/v1/Player/1144302439)](https://stackoverflow.com)
error: undefined is not a function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBkoG.jpg)

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
  
    import useApiHero from '../api/ApiHero';

    export const Main = () => {
    
        const { data } = useApiHero();

        data.map((post) => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>    
                    <Text>{post.identity.captainJackIdentityId}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        })
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#222',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
        },
    });
```

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    export const useApiHero = () => {
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);

        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                try {
                    const response = await fetch("https://docs.stratz.com/api/v1/Player/1144302439")
                    const json = await response.json();
                    setData(json);
                } catch (error) {
                    setError(error.message);
                } finally {
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            };

            fetchData();
        }, []);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code snippet

You are not returning any JSX from your `Main.js` component and it should be wrapped in `View` tag as:

```
<View>
      {data.map((post) => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{post.identity.captainJackIdentityId}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
```

You are not returning anything from `useApiHero.js` so by default it will return `undefined`. `data` should be returned as:

```
return { data };
```

You are importing `useApiHero` as

```
import useApiHero from '../api/ApiHero';
```

but it is not exported default. So either export default or import as named export as:

```
import { useApiHero } from '../api/ApiHero';
```

You are getting an object as response with some property as `identity, steamAccount`, `battlePass` etc.

You are trying to access `map` property on `data` which is not present so it will throw error because you are trying to invoke a function which is `undefined`.

`data` here is an `object` not an `array`

```
data.map((post) => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>    
                    <Text>{post.identity.captainJackIdentityId}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        })
```

---

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { useApiHero } from "./useApiHero";

const Main = () => {
  const { data } = useApiHero();
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <View>
      {data.battlePass?.map?.((post) => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{post.level}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#222",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default Main;
```

and

`useApiHero.js` as:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useApiHero = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://docs.stratz.com/api/v1/Player/1144302439"
        );
        const json = await response.json();
        setData(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return { data };
};
```